# ¿Cómo puedo conectar con un dispositivo bluetooth con mi app?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Buen día, verán quiero establecer conexión con un dispositivo médico que envía los datos de la medición por **bluetooth**.

Lo que quiero hacer es obtener los datos de las mediciones de este dispositivo (son solo tres números: **presión alta, presión baja, y ritmo**), sin embargo cuando reviso lo que entra en el `InputStream` veo que hay muchos datos que no se de donde salen y entre todos ellos van los dos valores que necesito.

Hice varias pruebas para tratar de encontrar una secuencia pero siempre aparecen en una posición diferente.

Por ejemplo esta es una de las capturas de datos que hice, en este caso los datos que el dispositivo me arrojaban eran 122,64,54.

```html
002 239 191 189 122 064 054 001 003 239 191 189 239 191 189 239 191 189 239 191 189 239 191 189 239 191 189 001 002 239 191 189 122 064 054 001 003 239 191 189 239 191 189 239 191 189 239 191 189 239 191 189 239 191 189
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Existe alguna forma de sólo obtener esos tres datos?
¿Algún tipo de filtrado para que no me aparezca lo demás?

Answer (score 1):

Esos números que mencionaste son los bytes del `InputStream` cada número es un byte del array `byte[]`, ese array puede ser texto, imagen, archivos, video. Supongo que en un dispositivo médico envía texto, pero no lo sé. Intenta convertir el array de bytes en texto (String), y si no es posible tendrás que consultar alguna guía para la conexión con dispositivos como estos para saber en qué convertir el array. Un array de bytes puede ser cualquier cosa, desde texto hasta el contenido de un archivo de extensión desconocida.

Cómo convertir en String

```
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
int length = inputStream.read(data);
String text = new String(data, 0, length);
```

Convierte el `inputStream` en el nombre de la variable asignada para el `InputStream` de Bluetooth. El nombre `inputStream` solo era un ejemplo.

Supuse que los números que mencionaste era parte de un array de bytes y el resultado era este convertido en `String`

```
�z4,�������z4,������
```

Es posible que el array de bytes sea de otro tipo de contenido y no texto plano. Tendrías que consultar la guía del dispositivo médico para conexiones Bluetooth,y si no tiene, no hay forma de interpretar ese array de bytes enviados por el dispositivo